# Modifying executable upon download (Like Ninite)

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I'm currently developing an application (Windows) that needs internal modifications upon download time.
Also, I'm delivering it using a Linux host, so, can't compile on demand as proposed.

How does [Ninite](http://www.ninite.com) deal with it?
In Ninite.com, each time you select different options, you get the same .exe, however, with minor modifications inside.

**Option 1**
Compile the program with predefined data (in Windows).
Use PHP to fseek the file and replace my custom strings.

**Option 2**
Append the original .EXE with a different resource file

**Other?**

Has someone developed something like this? What would be the best approach?
Thank you.

Comment: And what is the information you want to keep?

Comment: In the main application? everything except customer data.

Comment: Please edit your question to improve it. You changed its focus from "patching my executable" to "make my application persistent"

Comment: No, should be "patching on demand" :) I'm still reading more about it. That's why I gave the Ninite example, they patch it when you hit download.

Comment: Please explain the motivation of your question by editing it. Do you want to keep most of the running data (then focus on checkpointing & persistence), or do you want to have some tiny but persistent data (e.g. passwords) which survive restarting? Please explain what kind of data and what kind of application you have in mind.

Comment: Probably always the same executable but a packed executable holding N resourcefiles (dependingo n your selection). They may also just append link to the .exe at the end, then start opening and reading itself starting at the end. There are a lot of different options for this to be implemented. An easy way to have a bitfield at a given address and just patch it upon your selection. This would make it (as the links at the end) just a concatenated download.

Comment: That's it Sebastian. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just append data to the back of your original executable. The Windows PE file format is robust enough that this does not invalidate the executable itself. (It will however invalidate any existing digital signatures.)

Finding the start of this data can be a challenge if its size isn't known up front. In that case, it may be necessary to append the variable-length data, and then append the data length (itself a fixed length field - 4 bytes should do). To read the extra data, read the last 4 bytes to get the data length. Get the file length, subtract 4 for the length field, then subtract the variable length to get the start of the data.

Comment: Can appending 4 bytes to the end of executable change its execution?

Comment: @Danilo: Basically, `WinMain()` is still in its original position, and it only calls other functions that also remain at their original position. So those are not affected. Only code which knows that there is extra data appended will notice that data.

Answer (score 1):

The most portable way could be to have a *plugin* (whose path in wired inside your main program) inside your application. That plugin would be modified (e.g. on Linux by generating C++ code `gencod.cc`, forking a `g++ -Wall -shared -fPIC -O gencod.cc -o gencod.so` compilation, then `dlopen`-ing the `./gencod.so`) and your application could have something to generate the C++ source code of that plugin and to compile it.

I guess that the same might be doable on Windows (which I don't know). Probably the issue is to compile it (the compilation command would be different on Windows and on Linux). Beware that AFAIK on Windows a process cannot modify its own executable (but you should check).

Qt has a portable layer for plugins. See [QPluginLoader](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qpluginloader.html) & [Qt Plugins HowTo](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/plugins-howto.html)

Alternatively, don't modify the application, but use some [*persistent*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_%28computer_science%29) file or data (at a well defined place, -whose location or filepath is wired in the executable- preferably in textual format like [JSON](http://json.org), or maybe using [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/), or a real database) keeping the changing information. Read also about [application checkpointing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_checkpointing).

If you need to implement your specific application checkpointing, you'll better design your application very early with this concern. Study [garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) algorithms (a checkpointing procedure is similar to a precise copying GC) and read more about [continuations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation). See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26882187/841108) to a very similar question.